# sshCommand not found in Jenkins with "ssh pipeline steps" installed

Tags: jenkins, ssh, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I tried to use sshCommand on my Jenkinsfile and already have "SSH Pipeline Steps" plugin installed,
but Jenkins build error with:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 60: Unknown stage section "sshCommand". Starting with version 0.5, steps in a stage must be in a ‘steps’ block. @ line 60, column 5.
       stage('Remote SSH') {
       ^

WorkflowScript: 60: Multiple occurrences of the sshCommand section @ line 60, column 5.
       stage('Remote SSH') {
       ^

WorkflowScript: 60: Unknown stage section "sshCommand". Starting with version 0.5, steps in a stage must be in a ‘steps’ block. @ line 60, column 5.
       stage('Remote SSH') {
       ^

WorkflowScript: 60: Expected one of "steps", "stages", or "parallel" for stage "Remote SSH" @ line 60, column 5.
       stage('Remote SSH') {
       ^

4 errors
```

Here is my jenkinsfile:

```
def remote = [name: "${host}", host: "${host}", user: "root", allowAnyHosts: true]
stage('Remote SSH') {
      sshCommand remote: remote, command: "npm install"
      sshCommand remote: remote, command: "npm run start"
}
```

and here, it's already installed:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the interface to a plugin with Jenkins Pipeline, then the functions or methods exposed by the plugin must both be enclosed within a `steps` block:

```
stage('Remote SSH') {
  steps {
    sshCommand remote: remote, command: "npm install"
    sshCommand remote: remote, command: "npm run start"
  }
}
```

and your displayed error will be fixed.